# How can I pass a dynamic filter to the List component with Admin On Rest?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am using `Show` to show a student page. On the student page, I want to show a list of many courses and the list must be paginated.

```
    export const StudentShow = (props) => (
        <Show title='Student' {...props}>
            <SimpleShowLayout>
                // correctly displays the student ID
                <TextField label='id' source='id' />
                <ReferenceManyField
                    label='Courses'
                    target='course'
                    id='student.id'
                    reference='courses'>
                    // how can I properly pass the student ID to List?
                    <List {...props} filter={{ student: student.id }}>
                        <Datagrid>
                            <TextField source='code' />
                        </Datagrid>
                    </List>
                </ReferenceManyField>
            </SimpleShowLayout>
        </Show>
    );
```

The `ReferenceManyField` correctly makes an API call to `/courses/?student=<studentId>`, however `List` just makes a call to `/courses/`. I am not able to pass down the student ID to the `List` component.

How do I pass student ID to the `List` component?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the StudentId in localStorage on login and use that to create the filter. Haven't tested this. But I think it should work.

Also I am not sure that List is the component that you should be passing as a Child to ReferenceManyField. It should be an iterator component such as DataGrid or SingleFieldList.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#referencemanyfield

Comment: I don't want to store an arbitrary value in local storage. You are correct that List isn't meant to be a child component of ReferenceManyField. The reason I chose List was to use the built-in pagination, which DataGrid doesn't have (https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/561)

Comment: If the student ID is not the ID of the currently logged in student then you shouldnt store it yes. 

List filters can be changed by actions shot by the Filters prop. 

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/List.html#filters

You can try and wire in a default filter that is always on depending on the current student ID.

Comment: That's interesting. Are you aware if it's possible to set a permanent/default filters using the list filters component?

Comment: Haven't really had to explore that to be honest. But this basically means that the List Filters are dynamic and can be modified by actions. You just have to find a way to do it. Might be hacky, but should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the parent record by creating another component.

```
const Courses = props => (
    let studentRecord = props.record;

    <div className='field'>
        <ReferenceManyField
            target='course'
            reference='courses'>
            <List {...props} filter={{ student: studentRecord.id }}>
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField label='id' source='id' />
                </Datagrid>
            </List>
        </ReferenceManyField>
    </div>
);

export const StudentShow = (props) => (
    <Show title='Student' {...props}>
        <SimpleShowLayout>
            // correctly displays the student ID
            <TextField label='id' source='id' />
            <Courses {...props} />
        </SimpleShowLayout>
    </Show>
);
```